# How to resolve "conversion from string to type 'Double' is not valid"

Tags: vb.net

Here's what I have:

- 1 Richtextbox where all the text goes
- 1 Textbox where a user should input a number
- 1 radiobutton which the user should check

Here's what I want to happen:

- The user enters a number in the textbox (textbox1.text) and checks the checkbox (checkbox1.checked).
- The program automatically multiplies `"<ol>Item</ol>"` times the number entered in the textbox (textbox1.text) and shows it in the richtextbox (richtextbox1.text).

Here's my code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = "<ol>Item</ol>" * TextBox1.Text
    End If

End Sub
```

Here's what i'm getting:

```
Conversion from string "<ol>Item</ol>" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Maybe the * should be a & - string concatenation? Not sure this would work anyway, but you won't get the conversion error.

Comment: What do you mean by "The program automatically multiplies `"<ol>Item</ol>"` times the number entered in the textbox"? Can you clarify that?

Comment: `<ol>Item</ol>` would (probably) be an element from an xml document.  I'm guessing, but are there more instructions that you haven't shared concerning reading and parsing an xml document? (to obtain the value that is multiplied with the number that is entered in the textbox)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert `string` to `Double`:

```
Dim d As Double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
```

Now you can use `d` in any calculation before showing it in `RichTextBox1`

**EDIT:**

By reading your question again, now I get a feeling that you may be asking something else. Until you clarify the question, here is the other solution where I feel you want to display a string the number of times entered in the textbox. Here is the code for it:

```
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        For index = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
            sb.AppendLine("Your string here")
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
    End If
```

Comment: The error message provided by the OP is not coming from the value in the text box.  It is from the string literal that can't be converted to a numeric representation.

Comment: @MarkL - I realized that and that is why I was editing my question when you downvoted me :) Unfortunately, the question statement is vague too

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a loop. I assume you're trying to just repeat that string. But don't forget to add verification that `TextBox1.Text` is actually a number. You could use `IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text)` for that.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        For i As Integer = 0 to CInt(TextBox1.Text) - 1
            sb.Append("<ol>Item</ol>")
        Next    
        RichTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
     End If
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
         RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("<ol>Item</ol>", CInt(TextBox1.Text)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This should be fine but I suggest using `StringBuilder` instead as strings are immutable